# How can I update my account to use zhs. in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I run my code in VS Code, I get this message after every user interface input

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.

What can I do to use zsh and/or keep this messsage from appearing?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MAC, Apple has changed the default Interactive Shell from macOS Catalina.

But your Shell still could be bash.

if you want to change it to zsh, just run the following command in your terminal.

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

and if you want to stop message appearing every time you open terminal
just follow this article [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/hide-default-interactive-shell-is-now-zsh-in-terminal-on-macos/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20hide%20the,Use%20the%20Command%2BShift%2B.).